# A página HTML não está "chamando" o JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, validação

Estou com o seguinte problema, estou utilizando o Notepad++ como editor, e quando carrego a página HTML e preenche os dados do CPF, nada acontece, não há qualquer resposta.

Minha página HTML é:

```
 <html>
   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/aula09.js"></script>
    </head>
       <body>
      <form id="formulario">
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Validação e Formatação</legend>
        <label for="cpf">CPF:<label>
        <input name="cpf" type="text" />

        <label for="email">Email:<label>
        <input name="email" type="text" />

        <a href="#" onclick="validar()">Validar</a>
        </fieldset>
  </form></body></html>
```

Meu arquivo JavaScript é:

```
 function validar(){
    var formulario = document.getElementById("formulario");
    var cpf = formulario.cpf;
    var email = formulario.email;
    var re_cpf = /^([\d]{3})([\d]{3})([\d]{3})([\d]{2})$/;
    var re_email = /^([\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*@(([\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;   

    if(re_cpf.test(cpf.value)){
        alert("CPF válido");}
        else{
            alert("CPF inválido");
    }
}
```

Qual pode ser o problema?

Comment: Pode exibir o html completo do <form> ? Seu JS utiliza algumas informações que você não mostrou no HTML

Comment: Tem um `}` a mais no fim do código. Cheque sua identação e verifique o que aparece no console do navegador ao usar a página.

Comment: Não sei por que não apareceu o form completo. Vou tentar novamente abaixo:

Comment: <form id="formulario">
  <fieldset>
   <legend>Validação e Formatação</legend>
   <label for="cpf">CPF:<label>
   <input name="cpf" type="text" />
   
   <label for="email">Email:<label>
   <input name="email" type="text" />
   
   <a href="#" onclick="validar()">Validar</a>
  </fieldset>
 </form>

Comment: rafaels88, realmente existe um "}" a mais, porém mesmo corrigindo esse erro a função continua sem responder. Grato de qualquer forma.

Comment: @sscarvalho, o erro está no re_email, retire ele que irá funcionar

Comment: @sscarvalho Caso você tenha tido algum êxito, colabore com o SOpt e marque uma resposta como correta ou poste a sua solução.

Comment: window.onload = function() { document.getElementById ... }, você só pode usar getElementById após renderizar o elemento com ID

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O seu problema:

> e quando carrego a página HTML e preenche os dados do CPF, nada acontece, não há qualquer resposta.

Ao invés de `function validar () {`, utilize outro formato de escopo. No caso, `validar = function () { // ... }`. Veja:

```
validar = function () {
    var formulario = document.getElementById("formulario");
    var cpf = formulario.cpf;
    var email = formulario.email;
    var re_cpf = /^([\d]{3})([\d]{3})([\d]{3})([\d]{2})$/;
    var re_email = /^([\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*@(([\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;   

    if(re_cpf.test(cpf.value)){
        alert("CPF válido");}
        else{
            alert("CPF inválido");
    }
}
```

[Exemplo funcionando no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chiefGui/3358R/).

---

Ainda assim, o seu próximo erro é um problema com a expressão regular. Resolvi ele para você:

```
validar = function () {
    var formulario = document.getElementById("formulario");
    var cpf = formulario.cpf;
    var email = formulario.email;
    var re_cpf = /^([\d]{3})([\d]{3})([\d]{3})([\d]{2})$/;
    var re_email = /^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$/;   

    if(re_cpf.test(cpf.value)){
        alert("CPF válido");}
        else{
            alert("CPF inválido");
    }

    if(re_email.test(email.value)) alert('E-mail válido');
    else alert('E-mail inválido');
}
```

[Exemplo funcionando no jsFiddle (atualizado)](http://jsfiddle.net/chiefGui/3358R/1/)

---

## Por que o seu engatilhador `onclick` não está engatilhando `validar()`?

Baseado num questionário feito via um comentário do OP – muito bom por sinal! – vou responder essa pergunta com minimalismo:

```
function x () { 
  // do something
};
```

O formato acima é chamado de "declaração de função", que, por sua vez, é um modelo onde se salva a função para ser, digamos, usada "mais tarde" – não num primeiro instante. Como você pode ver, nenhuma variável é assinada à ela.

A seguir, o modelo proposto por mim:

```
x = function () { 
  // do something
};
```

Ele se chama "expressão de função" em tradução literal. Significa que você assina à "`x`" uma função para ser usada a qualquer instante em que `x` for executado.

**E qual a diferença prática?**

No seu caso específico, você está utilizando o observador `onclick` "inline"<sup>1</sup>. O escopo dele é o [DOM](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) e vai executar uma função que já existe no momento em que o cliente clicar no elemento que você designou para desencadear a função nomeada por você como `validar()`.

Enquanto `validar()` for uma função que "ainda" não existe, o seu efeito não será acionado.

**Mas como assim "ainda não existe"? Ele existe! Eu escrevi!**

Existe, mas o seu `<a>` ainda não sabe quem é ele. Se você escrever este HTML, o `function validar() {}` irá funcionar:

```
<a href="#" onclick="validar()">Validar que funciona</a>

<script>
    function validar() {
        alert('hello!');
    };
</script>
```

No seu caso, você está escrevendo JavaScript em um arquivo externo (`js/aula09.js`) e portanto, ele ainda não fora declarado para o DOM.

**Ainda não entendi**

Se você declarar uma função como previamente explicado no mesmo arquivo em que você a chama, tudo irá funcionar conforme o esperado. Enquanto você não fizer isso, as funções devem ser expressadas – explicadas para o DOM quem é quem.

Para ilustrar, dê uma olhada **[neste jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chiefGui/3BEh5/)**. O JavaScript que está na parte inferior esquerda não irá funcionar enquanto o que está embutido no seu HTML executará o seu papel – isso acontece porque o JavaScript deste quadrado branco inferior é "externo" para o HTML.

Para fins de comparação, se você colocar em um arquivo `.js` externo este conteúdo:

```
f = function () {
  alert('Olá!');
};
```

E colocar em um arquivo `.html` isto:

```
<a href="#" onclick="x()">Funciona!</a>
<a href="#" onclick="f()">Também funciona!</a>

<script>
    function x() {
        alert('hello!');
    };
</script>
```

Perceberá que ambos irão funcionar, exatamente como **[neste outro jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chiefGui/3BEh5/1/)**.

---

<sup>1: Neste caso, "inline" significa que você está usando de JavaScript via HTML na linha do seu elemento – não é um efeito [unobtrusivo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).</sup>

Comment: Muito obrigado, Guilherme Oderdenge, agora funcionou. Contudo, como gostaria não só de fazer funcionar, mas principalmente de entender o que estou fazendo, gostaria ainda que me esclarecesse a seguinte questão. Estou fazendo um exercício onde o autor usa "function validar () {" ao invés de "validar = function () {". No vídeo ele mostra que funciona do mesmo jeito. Por que comigo só está funcionando o formato de escopo que você sugeriu?

Comment: @sscarvalho Linda pergunta! Fiz questão de reformular a minha resposta para melhor te esclarecer. Espero que agora fique claro!

Comment: O `validarQueNaoFunciona` **[funciona sim](http://jsfiddle.net/3BEh5/2/)**. Você caiu na pegadinha de escopo do jsfiddle, que coloca os scripts numa função de onload por padrão, retirando-os do escopo global. Sua explicação sobre `function x` vs `x = function` está incorreta, na verdade é o contrário: `function x(){}` sofre hoisting e está disponível desde o topo do script, enquanto em `x = function` ocorre hoisting somente da declaração de variável, mas não da atribuição do valor.

Comment: Não é pegadinha, @bfavaretto. Você selecionou `No wrap - in <body>` – se consultar o DOM, o JavaScript vai estar lá, entrando exatamente na questão por mim levantada onde o escopo se "perder" quando o JavaScript é **declarado** externamente.

Comment: Guilherme, não faz diferença se o arquivo é externo ou não, nem se é carregado no head ou no fim do body. http://plnkr.co/edit/IblNhkr7klHNELKD989I?p=preview

Comment: PS: O downvote é meu, pois a resposta contém informações incorretas que podem confundir as pessoas (me avise se quiser discutir isso, podemos falar no chat).

Answer (score 1):

Vi aqui que seu código tem um problema com a expressão regular que vc definiu na variável 're_email'. Com isso o código está quebrando e acaba não executando o seu código.

Além disso tinham algumas tags que não estavam fechadas.

Fiz as correções aqui e agora funciona com o código abaixo. Depois dê uma olhada apenas na expressão que você criou naquela variável 're_email', para validação do e-mail.

Espero ter ajudado. Abraços.

```
            <html>
                <head><script>
                     function validar(){
                        var formulario = document.getElementById("formulario");
                        alert(formulario);
                        var cpf = formulario.cpf.value;
                        alert(cpf);
                        var email = formulario.email.value;
                        alert(email);
                        var re_cpf = /^([\d]{3})([\d]{3})([\d]{3})([\d]{2})$/;

                        if(re_cpf.test(cpf)){
                        alert("CPF válido");
                        } else {
                        alert("CPF inválido");
                        }
                    }
                </script></head>
                <body>
                    <form id="formulario">
                        <fieldset>
                        <legend>Validação e Formatação</legend>
                        <label for="cpf">CPF:</label>
                        <input name="cpf" type="text" />

                        <label for="email">Email:</label>
                        <input name="email" type="text" />

                        <a href="#" onclick="javascript:validar()">Validar</a>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: `"Invalid regular expression: missing )"`

Comment: Muito obrigado, Dias, agora também está funcionando comigo. Só que estava utilizando arquivos distintos para HTML e JavaScript. E fazendo isso continua ocorrendo o problema. Segue abaixo a forma como escrevi e que acho que deveria funcionar: JavaScript:  function validar(){
    var formulario = document.getElementById("formulario");
    var cpf = formulario.cpf.value;
    var email = formulario.email.value;
    var re_cpf = /^([\d]{3})([\d]{3})([\d]{3})([\d]{2})$/;
    if(re_cpf.test(cpf)){
        alert("CPF válido");}
        else{
            alert("CPF inválido");
    }
}

Comment: HTML: <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/aula09.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="formulario">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Validação e Formatação</legend>
        <label for="cpf">CPF:</label>
        <input name="cpf" type="text" />

        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input name="email" type="text" />

        <a href="#" onclick="validar()">Validar</a>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Editei minha pergunta.

Comment: Mude `<form id="formulario">` para: `<form id="formulario" name="formulario" method="post">`, ao invés de usar getElementById, experimente: `document.formulario`; para cpf: `document.formulario.cpf`. Você está pegando um atributo do documento do form, e não do dom do objeto renderizado... GetElementById não considera o objeto dom, e sim o elemento renderizado na sua view, que não tem atributos do tipo name por exemplo.