# Java script externo da página html não está funcionando

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Estou com um problema nas minhas páginas após tentar colocar o js em um arquivo externo ele simplesmente deixou de funcionar, e não consegui achar o erro até o momento.

**Segue os códigos**

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="funcjs.js"></script>//dentro da tag head
<a href="javascript:showhide('login')" style="float:right;" >Login</a>//dentro da tag body
```

**JS (dentro do arquivo funcjs.js)**

Inicialmente ele estava assim:

```
function showhide(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   e.style.display = (e.style.display == 'inline') ? 'none' : 'inline';
}
```

porém após pesquisar e achar isso: [A página HTML não está "chamando" o JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27354/a-p%C3%A1gina-html-n%C3%A3o-est%C3%A1-chamando-o-javascript)

**ficou assim**

```
showhide = function (id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   e.style.display = (e.style.display == 'inline') ? 'none' : 'inline';
}
```

Quando o 1 código JS estava na própria página html ele estava funcionando normalmente, não fiz nenhuma alteração no código html após a mudança, tem alguma coisa errada na forma que estou tentando chamar essa função?

**EDIT:SEGUE A TAG HEAD DO CÓDIGO COMPLETA ASSIM COMO A DIV SHOWHIDE**

**HEAD**

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,user-scalable=no">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="funcjs.js"></script>
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=pt-BR'></script>
```

**DIV**

```
<div id="login" style="display:none;">
            <form action="login.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <p><input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" placeholder="Usuário"></p>
                <p><input type="password" name="senha" id="senha" placeholder="Senha"></p>
                <p><input type="submit" value="login" id="entrar"/></p>
                <input type="hidden" name="entrar" value="login">
                <p value="error" style="display:none;">por favor preencha os campos!</p>
            </form>
</div>
```

**OBS:** Uso esse script em quase todas as páginas, e a única coisa que compartilham é a head, e em nenhuma delas funcionou após colocar o código no arquivo externo.

Answer (score 1):

Olá. Conforme o teste que eu fiz está funcionando normalmente a sua função. O exemplo que mostra em [A página HTML não está "chamando" o JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27354/a-p%C3%A1gina-html-n%C3%A3o-est%C3%A1-chamando-o-javascript) mostra que o arquivo .js externo foi chamado dentro da pasta /js. O exemplo que fiz para simular a tua situação estava com todos os arquivos dentro da mesma pasta e adicionei a div com o id='login' que não constava no teu exemplo.

Certifique-se que o caminho correto do seu arquivo .js está referenciado corretamente;
Certifique-se que existe o elemento com o id='login'.

Comment: Sim o id está correto, e o caminho também pois abri o código fonte e o link que referencia ele estava abrindo o código corretamente, realmente não estou entendendo o motivo do não funcionamento...

Comment: Poste o html inteiro para analisar melhor por favor.

Comment: coloquei toda parte do código que acredito que possa estar causando algum conflito, como a página é meio grande acho díficil postar ela completa aqui.

Comment: Olá Jessica. Refiz o exemplo e ainda funcionou corretamente com o html e o conteúdo do cabeçalho que me forneceu. Existe ainda a possibilidade do teu arquivo .js estar sendo referenciado de uma forma incorreta. Qual o erro do console do browser quando tenta clica no link 'Login' ? O arquivo da tua página e o arquivo funcjs.js estão em pastas diferentes? Só confirmando, o efeito que queres quando aperta no link 'Login' é que apareça/oculte o formulário não é?

Comment: Sim preciso que ele oculte/mostre esse formulário, como disse anteriormente o arquivo está sendo referenciado corretamente, está na mesma pasta, não me retorna nenhum errro, ele apenas não faz a função de mostrar/esconder. Realmente não estou conseguindo entender, visto que não é só nessa página que não está funcionando e possuo outras páginas muito mais simples em que o erro persiste.

Comment: @Wel, veja se isso é o esperado <https://liveweave.com/#&togetherjs=oOa67SEqiG>

Comment: não entendi, o código que você enviou não parece ter ligação nenhum com o que postei...

Comment: Amigo, é apenas o código que postou acima. Me relate o que difere, pois conforme tu mencionou mais cedo, ele deveria ocultar e mostrar o formulário ao click do link, e é o que está acontecendo.

Comment: ok, mas no caso o código não está funcionando porque está no mesmo arquivo nesse caso? Pois mesmo retirando a referencia js dentro da tag head ele continua funcionando, e como eu disse o código só parou de funcionar após coloca-lo em um arquivo externo...

Comment: Sim sim, eu coloquei o código lá apenas pra confirmar o seu funcionamento, pois como te citei, o código funciona no arquivo externo aqui em minha máquina. Tu teria esse código em Git por acaso?